# What should be mentioned in build stage and deploy stange in Jenkins script...what is difference between deploy and build state.?

Tags: jenkins

What should be mentioned in build stage and deploy stange in Jenkins script...what is difference between deploy and build state.?

Try to search it on Google for better understanding..but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Deploy should mean take all of my artifacts and either copy them to a server, or execute them on a server. It should truly be a simple process.

Build means, process all of my code/artifacts and prepare them for deployment. Meaning compile, generate code, package, etc